# Rendering dynamic content in Antd Form input as per initialValues

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, antd

In my project, I have a article form which is editable. Upon mounting the form, I fetched the form data from the API and passed the data as a part of initial values in the form props.

This is how the **Form Code** looks so far:

```
export const SingleArticle: React.FC<Props> = ({
  singleArticleDetails,
}: Props) => {

  const {
    title,
    commentsAllowed,
    content,
  } = singleArticleDetails;


  return (
    <Form
      name="editArticle"
      labelCol={{ span: 8 }}
      style={{ maxWidth: 600 }}
      initialValues={{
        title,
        commentsAllowed,
        content,
      }}
      onFinish={onFinish}
      onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}
      autoComplete="off"
    >
      <Form.Item
        label="Title"
        name="title"
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: "This field is required!",
          },
        ]}
      >
        <Input placeholder="Enter a title for the article" />
      </Form.Item>

      <Form.List name="content">
        {(fields, { add, remove }, { errors }) => {
          return (
            <>
              {fields.map(({ key, name }) => (
                <Form.Item
                  key={key}
                  name={["name"]}
                  rules={[
                    {
                      required: true,
                      message: "This field is required!",
                    },
                  ]}
                >
                  <TextArea rows={10} placeholder="Add Article Content" />
                </Form.Item>
              ))}
            </>
          );
        }}
      </Form.List>

      <Form.Item
        label="Comments Allowed"
        name="commentsAllowed"
        rules={[{ required: true, message: "This field is required!" }]}
      >
        <Select placeholder="Select Value">
          <Option value="Yes">Yes</Option>
          <Option value="No">No</Option>
        </Select>
      </Form.Item>

      <Form.Item wrapperCol={{ offset: 8, span: 16 }}>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};
```

**API response**:

```
{
    "_id": "6474ee24b5c388d4becb23c3",
    "title": "New Article After Delete",
    ],
    "commentsAllowed": true,
    "content": [
        {
            "para": "Content 1 or paragraph one of the article"
        },
        {
            "para": "Content 2 or paragraph two of the article"
        }
    ]
}
```

**This is the UI so far**:

[image]

Now The issue I am facing is that I'm trying to load the existing API response of '***content***' into the form field "content". For this, I tried to use the concept of **<Form.Item>** from [Antd](https://ant.design/components/form#formitem), but something doesn't make sense.

Two **TextAreas** were rendered as per the length of the '**content**' property from API, but their data is not being populated in these TextAreas. Not sure, if some key step is missing.

I'm new to utilizing Antd for Form handling. Any help to resolve the same will be really helpful.

Comment: Form.Item has incorrect name inside Form.List. Change it to `name={[name, 'para']}`. This will fix the issue

Comment: @MuhammadNoumanRafique That Worked. Thanks a lot! Can you help explain what exactly this syntax is? When I console.log(fields), it print an array like this: `[
    {
        "name": 0,
        "key": 0,
        "isListField": true,
        "fieldKey": 0
    },
    {
        "name": 1,
        "key": 1,
        "isListField": true,
        "fieldKey": 1
    }
]` I don't see property 'para' present here

Comment: It's nothing special here. You can say antd Form.List provides you an array by checking length of content and you can use it map your form fields. Here name is index of field. Anything inside Form.List is consider as ListField and antd will concat the list name `content` with the name of Form.Field. So Form.Item path internally becomes like this. `['content', name, 'para']`.